# OpenGL ES - Draw Triangle with line only?

Tags: opengl-es

Is there a way to draw a triangle with line only ?
I think GL_TRIANGLES option make triangle filled with color.

Answer (score 16):

Set the fill mode with [glPolygonMode(face, model)](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml):

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
```

You have to set this every frame

Comment: This was indeed the solution in my case. For whatever reason, triangles are rendered incorrectly through the use of GL_LINE_STRIP, but your answer produced the desired effect.

However, I also had to disable GL_CULL_FACE and reenable it afterwards to produce a proper wireframe

Comment: @Yattabyte If you want to use `GL_LINE_STRIP`, you have to list the first vertex twice. Once at the beginning and once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to draw a triangle with line only?

Use `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP` , or `GL_LINE_LOOP` (difference see [here](http://cse.csusb.edu/tongyu/courses/cs420/notes/drawing.php)) with the same vertices that you use for `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only rendering a single triangle at a time you can use `GL_LINE_LOOP`. it will connect the first and last, so if you have more than one triangle, it won't work.